# SQL Server 2012 replace string in Select statement in Dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to replace part of a string in a select statement in Dynamic sql but I receive errors.

Here is my code:

```
set @oldTblPrefix = 'ABC'
set @newTblPrefix = 'XYZ'
set @sourcetid = 17
set @template ='
INSERT INTO ' +@DB + '.[Tforms]
           (id
           ,[tablename])

     select id,
            replace([tablename],'+@oldTblPrefix+','+@newTblPrefix+')
     from '+ @DB+ '.[Tforms] where tid=' +str(@sourcetid) 
exec sp_Executesql @template
```

But I receive these errors:

> Invalid column name 'ABC'. Invalid column name 'XYZ'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add single quotation marks - two on each side - before and after your variables. One to show up in resulting string, and other as escape character

Replace execute with print at the end until you get it, and check if the resulting query is correct.

```
set @template ='
INSERT INTO ' +@DB + '.[Tforms]
           (id
           ,[tablename])

     select id,
            replace([tablename],'''+@oldTblPrefix+''','''+@newTblPrefix+''')
     from '+ @DB+ '.[Tforms] where tid=' +str(@sourcetid) 
PRINT @template
--exec sp_Executesql @template
```